# Dojo select drop down on expand changing default value

Tags: dojo, dropdownbox

[image]

I'm setting default value for Dojo select drop down i.e  id =-999 from the json object.
This works fine but on click of selectbox when expanding the default value is changing to second position and id= 29 is setting as default (first position).
This problem occurs mostly in Chrome browser.
Attached are the images of json object and ui behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you have to share some code to get more help. Do you see the same behaviour in this example? http://jsfiddle.net/froden/oqjym25f/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `labelAttr` when setting the `store`, e.g.

```
new Select({
    store: new MemoryStore({ data: g_data(), getLabel: function(o) {return o.label;} }),
    labelAttr: "label",
    value: "-999",
    onChange: function(v) { document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Selected " + v; }
}).placeAt("container").startup();
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/k63h12ux/2/

If you don't want the labels to be sorted, add `sortByLabel: false`. This will also solve this issue.

```
new Select({
    store: new MemoryStore({ data: g_data(), getLabel: function(o) {return o.label;} }),
    sortByLabel: false,
    value: "-999",
    onChange: function(v) { document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Selected " + v; }
}).placeAt("container").startup();
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/z4w0bx9k/1/

The cause of this issue is around [following line](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/form/_FormSelectWidget.js#L366) of `dijit.form._FormSelectWidget`. If no `labelAttr` is provided and with default value of `sortByLabel` set to `true`, items from the store will be stored using the wrong condition and hence gives the wrong order.

```
var labelAttr = this.labelAttr;
items.sort(function(a, b){
    return a[labelAttr] > b[labelAttr] ? 1 : b[labelAttr] > a[labelAttr] ? -1 : 0;
});
```

From the `dijit.form._FormSelectWidget` doc, it also says:

> If `store` is set, labelAttr must be set too, unless store is an old-style
>   dojo.data store rather than a new dojo/store.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,actually labelAttr: "label",
    value: "-999",sortByLabel: false, these three lines of code fixed my issue .